# Faster way to tag a cell if its column name appears in preceding cells of the same row

Tags: r, dataframe

- I have a big data frame (~ 280000 rows x 1200 columns), each row represents a basket of items.
- The first column has the basket id.
- The next ~120 columns have either a 4 digit item code (of one of the items present in the basket) or are blank (for remainder of 120 cells after all items of the basket have been accounted for).
- The subsequent columns (from 121 till 1200) are each named with one of the unique 4 digit item codes from the items universe. All these columns are blank.

Now, I want to tag the cells in these columns (121 to 1200), if that item (the column name) appears in that row/basket.

Following is a smaller version of the dataframe (df);

```
df <- data.frame(BasketID = c("001", "002"),
                 Item1 = c(1001, 1002), Item2 = c(1002,""), Item3 = "",
                 `1001` = "", `1002` = "", `1003` = "", check.names=F)

BasketID   Item1   Item2   Item3   ...   1001   1002   1003
001        1001    1002
002        1003
```

Below is what I require;

```
BasketID   Item1   Item2   Item3   ...   1001   1002   1003
001        1001    1002                  tag    tag
002        1003                                        tag
```

I wrote the following for loop to achieve the above;

```
for (i in rownames(df)) {  

    for (j in colnames(df[,121:1200])) {  

        if (j %in% df[i,121:1200]) { 

            df[i,j] <- "tag"
        }
    }
}
```

However, since the dataframe is big, the above command is taking forever to run forcing me to abort midway. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks v. much in advance!!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: Hi @jogo, couldn't find the link you shared useful for my problem. Infact, the link popped when I was looking up for a solution to this problem. There, there is a separate vector using which dataframe is being filtered. however, what I need is lookups within my dataframe without filtering. Let me know if you can think of something else as well. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please giva [a small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? i.e. edit your question.

Comment: You can take the example I shared in my post. Consider it to be a 2x6 dataframe like in the example. If I had to run the for loop (shared in my post) on this 2x6 df, I guess it would run in a jiffy. It's just that my actual dataframe is a much bigger version of this 2x6 df, that's why not possible to share here.

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` to show your dataframe (or a definition of it). What value is in your dataframe `df` for `BasketID` 001 and `Item3`?

Comment: Hey @jogo, have modified my post as requested. To answer your question, currently there is no value in BasketID 001 and Item3.

Comment: In your example there is a value: it is character with length 0.

Comment: @jogo Yes, stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

This might be more easily done using the data.table package. Convert into a long format using `melt`. Subset to those with valid value. Then pivot the data using length > 0 as the `fun.aggregate`:

```
library(data.table)
dcast.data.table(
    melt(setDT(df), id.vars="BasketID"),
    BasketID ~ value,
    function(x) length(x) > 0,
    subset=.(value!=""))

#the join the results with original dataset to get OP's desired format
tags[df, on=.(BasketID)]

#    BasketID  1001  1002  1003 Item1 Item2 Item3
# 1:      001  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  1001  1002      
# 2:      002 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  1003
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(BasketID = c("001", "002"),
    Item1 = c(1001, 1003), Item2 = c(1002,""), Item3 = "")
```

Comment: `D <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars="BasketID");
dcast(D[value!=""], BasketID ~ value, function(x) if (length(x)!=0) "tag" else "")`